# ASP dot net mvc C# - Can't make a session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I can't seem to make a session variable. 
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

[image]

Why is this not possible?

[image]

Comment: You have to reference the assembly

Comment: is this .net core?

Comment: @DavideVitali That makes no sense

Comment: @DanielA.White It *should* be, ASP.NET MVC does not have an `IActionResult` interface

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#session-state

Comment: If this *is* ASP.NET Core, use `HttpContext.Session`

Comment: Yes this is Dot net core

Comment: If this is ASP.NET Core, use the ASP.NET Core tag, not the ASP.NET MVC one.

Comment: I added this : using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session;

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core's controllers don't have a `Session` property. You will have to configure the session and inject `ISession`. [Read about it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#session-state).

Comment: Hmmm. you can use `HttpContext.Session` without injecting `ISession`, unless I'm missing something

Comment: That's correct. There's no need to inject `ISession`, and it's actually pretty non-standard to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SAMPLE_SESSION_VAL1]